# Get error "may be sending automated queries" in Google Drive API using Soup (Vala)

Tags: google-drive-api, google-authentication, vala, bearer-token

The Google Drive API at times returns a response of an HTML page with contents:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Sorry...</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><b>
                        <font face=sans-serif size=10>
                            <font color=#4285f4>G</font>
                            <font color=#ea4335>o</font>
                            <font color=#fbbc05>o</font>
                            <font color=#4285f4>g</font>
                            <font color=#34a853>l</font>
                            <font color=#ea4335>e</font>
                        </font>
                    </b></td>
                <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 50%">
                    <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;">Sorry...</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 4em;">
        <h1>We\'re sorry...</h1>
        <p>... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can\'t process
            your request right now.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 4em;">See <a href="https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640">Google Help</a> for
        more information.<br /><br /></div>
    <div style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;"><a href="https://www.google.com">Google Home</a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This happens  when calling the https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/file_id endpoint with the aprameter "?alt=media" in order to get the content of the file.

I've not exeded any quota.

I don't get this error in other calls like https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=trashed = False .

The error ocurrs in an app that I've written in Vala (https://github.com/bcedu/VGrive). This app has been working well without getting this error. It started ocurring when Google changed the authentication, instead of using an access token in a query parameter,  using an HTTP header instead. I made this changes and the problem was solved in some requests (like searching files as I mentioned) but I'm still getting the error when I want to download files.

I'm using the Google Drive api v3

I'm using the vala library Soup (a well known Gnome library https://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/unstable/) to make the requests. You can test the error with the following code:

```
public static int main(string[] args) {
    // THIS DOESNT WORKS
    string method = "GET";
    string file_id = "";  // Some Google Drive File ID
    string uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%s?alt=media".printf(file_id);
    string access_token = "";  // A valid acces_token

    Soup.Session session = new Soup.Session ();
    Soup.Message message = new Soup.Message (method, uri);

    message.request_headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer %s".printf(access_token));
    session.send_message (message);

    // Response is stored in message.response_body.data
    print("AUTOMATED QUERY ERROR:\n"+(string)message.response_body.data+"\n\n");


    // THIS WORKS
    uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=trashed = False and 'root' in parents";
    session = new Soup.Session ();
    message = new Soup.Message (method, uri);

    message.request_headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer %s".printf(access_token));
    session.send_message (message);

    // Response is stored in message.response_body.data
    print("THIS WORKS, SO TOKEN IS PASSES CORRECTLLY...\n"+(string)message.response_body.data+"\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Run the test with:

```sh
valac --pkg libsoup-2.4 GoogleTest.vala
./GoogleTest
```

You will need to install:

- libsoup-2.4
- valac

I expect both a succesfull response or an autthentication error, but not an html page saying I'm making automated queries. It is an API, it is suposed to be used by apps and not only humans.

**Am i missing something from google drive API? Do i have to do an additional step to pass the bearer token throught Soup?**

Comment: Are you getting this error consistently or just from time to time? Could you check if this error only happen with big files? Have you try to download your files by chunks?. I suspect that you are doing all the HTTP request without the help of the official libraries, maybe try to go to [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and check there if you are doing all the correct requests with the right scopes.

Comment: I always get this error, with small and big files. When you call the api to donwnload a file it already give tou chunks, the problem is that I don't get the first chunk, I get an error.

There is no Google Drive API library for Vala, so I had to read the docs and make my own library, s yes, I make the whole HTTP request.

Comment: Are you able to get that HTTP request inside the OAuth Playground or `curl`? This seems like it should work correctly, maybe is a problem with the `Soup` library.

Comment: I've tried to make the same request with curl, the results are the same:

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer the_acces_token" "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/file_id?alt=media"`

Comment: I've opened an issue to google issues tracker as it seems to be a problem tith the api https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153717392

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments the problem is being tracked in the google forums. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/153717392

The issue there seemed to have been solved and OP has no longer problems using the API.